# 3d triangle roof house model in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d, 3d-model

1. Hi, I know that the is a possibility to "build" 3d structures - or rather to visualize shapefiles in 3d - in QGIS.
   ie. a "reconstruction" of a redoubt I have created earlier
   [image]
2. Alhtough I have not found a case study where a rectengular-like features where visualized.
3. What I am looking for is to (re)"construct" a simple 3d visualization of ALS-derived dtm interpretation of a POW camp from IWW - most of the buildings where pit-houses. To put it simply a rectengular roof sticking out of ground.
   [image]
4. I know that it would probably be better for me to use some CAD software, but I have none experience with them and I do have GIS skills. I do not have access to ArcGIS and if possible I prefere not to use it.

Comment: What should be the output format? would a website be a soulution?

Comment: You have a raster DEM of the area and a shapefile with a height to extrude? If R is an option, it's relatively straightforward to build that scene with the rgl package.

Comment: so what You are suggesting is a model where DTM and the housing features are merged in one?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use QGIS I suggest to use this workflow:

**Data needed:**

- DEM of the area of interest
- A colada Model which represents the buildings( models can be downloaded from [this website](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/index.html) or can be created [with sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/))
- A Point layer which represents the place, where the buildings used to stand
- Optional: Fields on the point layer which may hold rotation, height or scale values
- Optional: a base map or Orthophoto to use as overlay

**Software need:**

- QGIS Version 2.14 or higher
- QGIS2threejs Plugin
- Sketchup: This might be the case if you want to be very realistic in the building of THE POW camp. You can use Sketchup (I am aware its a CAD software and op said he prefer not to use) to create the models if you dont find any suitable models in the provided links.

**Workflow:**

- Load the data into QGIS
- Deactivate every layer which you don't want to **see** in the final map ( for example the DEM and the points)
- You will have something similar to the first image 
  [image]
- in the QGis2threejs tool, you chose COLLADA model as object type for the point layer.(see image 2)

[image]
- as Collada file, you either choose one which is exported via Sketchup or a file downloaded. 
- The values for scale and rotation I mostly use trial and error approach and use fixed values. 
- As DEM use the file with the heights and use it as the DEM layer
- When clicking on run you will get a website which allows flying through the model as shown in image 3

[image]

I've tested the workflow with QGIS 2.18.12 SRTM Data and fast created Collada models